# Attribute Error for gensim.models.docvecs.doctag_syn0norm

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, word2vec, doc2vec

I am writing code for Gensim Doc2Vec model in Python 3 
This is the snippet I am running:

```
model1.docvecs.doctag_syn0norm =  (model1.docvecs.doctag_syn0 / sqrt((model1.docvecs.doctag_syn0 ** 2).sum(-1))[..., newaxis]).astype(REAL)[d_indices]
```

I am getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: can t set attribute
```

The right hand value is getting calculated when I tested separately but is not getting assigned.

I feel that it is a setter issue as I can't set the value to what I want for that class attribute.

Let me know if there's any work-around as I don't want to change gensim's source code.

[Clone my repo](https://github.com/satya-tsky/NETL-Automatic-Topic-Labelling-) and run get_labels.py in model run folder following Readme instructions to reproduce the error.

It's in line 90 of cand_gen.py

The full error stack trace is:

```
Extracting candidate labels
models loaded
Data Gathered
cand_generation.py:71: DeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated `syn0` (Attribute will be removed in 4.0.0, use self.vectors instead).
  model1.wv.syn0norm = (model1.wv.syn0 / sqrt((model1.wv.syn0 ** 2).sum(-1))[..., newaxis]).astype(REAL)
cand_generation.py:71: DeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated `syn0norm` (Attribute will be removed in 4.0.0, use self.vectors_norm instead).
  model1.wv.syn0norm = (model1.wv.syn0 / sqrt((model1.wv.syn0 ** 2).sum(-1))[..., newaxis]).astype(REAL)
cand_generation.py:89: DeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated `doctag_syn0` (Attribute will be removed in 4.0.0, use docvecs.vectors_docs instead).
  model1.docvecs.doctag_syn0norm =  (model1.docvecs.doctag_syn0 / sqrt((model1.docvecs.doctag_syn0 ** 2).sum(-1))[..., newaxis]).astype(REAL)[d_indices]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cand_generation.py", line 89, in <module>
    model1.docvecs.doctag_syn0norm =  (model1.docvecs.doctag_syn0 / sqrt((model1.docvecs.doctag_syn0 ** 2).sum(-1))[..., newaxis]).astype(REAL)[d_indices]
AttributeError: can t set attribute
Executing Unsupervised model
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "unsupervised_labels.py", line 33, in <module>
    test_chunk_size = len(label_list[0])
IndexError: list index out of range
Executing Supervised Model
page Rank models loaded
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "supervised_labels.py", line 49, in <module>
    test_chunk_size = len(label_list[0])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: What's the full error stack? Why do you want to assign into that attribute?

Comment: @gojomo I am trying to normalize the values and set them manually hence assigning into that attribute.

Comment: But why do you want to put your normalized values there? And, what's the full error stack?

Comment: @gojomo I'm trying to run the model_run/get_labels.py code in this repo:https://github.com/sb1992/NETL-Automatic-Topic-Labelling-/tree/master/model_run to automatically labels topics to text. This code is in Python2 but Anaconda does not support downloading packages for Python2 hence I converted the code to Python3 and tried running it.

You can clone my fork where I made the changes and run it.
https://github.com/satya-tsky/NETL-Automatic-Topic-Labelling-

Comment: @gojomo I have updated the question with entire error stack trace and linked my repo there too.

Comment: Thanks, but the stack trace you've provided doesn't show the "AttributeError" you initially asked about.

Comment: @gojomo check now. I have edited it. Also let me know if you manage to run the original repo in Python2 in Anaconda by any chance.

Answer (score 1):

First & generally, it's not necessarily likely a 4-year-old repository that hasn't been updated regularly would continue to work with continuously-updated versions of Gensim - which has had about 15 releases, moving from version 0.13.3 to 3.8.3, since that repository was last updated.

With such an old example, you might want to search fresher examples of what you want to do, or if you absolutely need to use that base, reach out to its original author for advice.

More specifically: your code is trying to assign into an obsolete property of the model, no longer used by the latest Gensim code. But, to maintain backward compatibility with code that read the old value, the latest code includes a property accessor *only* - no setter. Trying to set a value for which there is no settor method creates the error you're seeing.

Why isn't there a settor? The `_norm` internal arrays have always been calculated internally by Gensim as needed (chiefly via the `.init_sims()` method, before doing bulk similarity operations). It wasn't foreseen that anyone would want to assign into it – and indeed, it's not wise to do so. It wasn't wise when that code was written, either - such code should trigger Gensim's own calculation.

The absolute smallest-change to the code you're using that **might** work would be to both assign-into, and then later access, some other property name. That could be any property name of your choosing. (It is *only* the overlap with a name that used to be significant to Gensim that's causing the error.) This would retain the unwise external calculation/modification, and if Gensim's own calculation is later triggered through more normal use, it'd result in double-memory usage. But if hewing close to what the original code does, this is the minimal change. (There might be other errors, for similar reasons related to the code being outdated, after this one is overcome.)

A slightly-more compatible approach would be to fix the code you're using to trigger, and reuse, Gensim's own normed-vallues calculation instead. This would likely involve:

1. Calling `model.docvecs.init_sims()` instead of assigning into `model1.docvecs.doctag_syn0norm`
2. Changing any accesses of `.doctag_syn0norm` to instead use the new name for the same internal property – as highlighted in the `DeprecationWarning` messages in your output – which is `.vectors_norm`.

Good luck!

Comment: Yeah I'll contact the author

Comment: @sdasara did you manage to fix this ? I also meet the same issue and tried to contact the author but no help. Any news from your side? Tks !

Comment: @user1314404, yea bro, do you manage to fix it ?